# Lockscreen Clock Format?

Tags: settings, greeter, clock

I can't seem to find where to change the lockscreen time format. Currently its displaying AM+PM clock, whilst my system is set to use English British and my Date+Time is set to 24h (Its displaying correctly in the system it self). In the gnome desktop environment there is an option to change the login screen settings inside "Region and Language", but I can't seem to find it anywhere within Elementary Loki. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: I guess this question has already been answered http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/698/how-to-change-the-language-of-the-date-time-in-the-login-page and http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5225/cannot-change-lockscreen-calender-widgets-language

Comment: Didn't notice those. But I tired both and when set to "United Kingdom" the clock stays 12h format. I will report this bug. Thanks.